# ezpublish header links how do I push/remove link?

Tags: php, ezpublish

just don't know how can I control over the visualization of links in my header (ezPublish 4.3)

thanks

Comment: What links are you referring to ? Top menu ? Log-in/Register ones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the template debugger on in your settings/override/site.ini.append

```
[TemplateSettings]
Debug=enabled
#ShowXHTMLCode=disabled
#ShowMethodDebug=enabled
#ShowUsedTemplates=enabled
#UseFormatting=enabled
#NodeTreeCaching=disabled
TemplateCompile=disabled
TemplateOptimization=disabled
TemplateCache=disabled
#DevelopmentMode=enabled
#CompileComments=enabled
#CompileAlwaysGenerate=enabled
#DesignLocationCache=enabled
```

Now you can see the used template for your header, when you display it in Frontend. If you want to chanche, search the used template file and make an override for it.

Create an own template in extension/[YOUREXTENSION]/design/override/.../yourChangedHeader.tpl

Now create an [override rule](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-override-conditions) in the file override.ini

Don't forget to uncomment the template debugger settings after ;)

Cheers. Frank